# is there a site as SourceForge for Android?

Tags: android, sourceforge

I Want to gain a little experience in developing Android apps in the upcoming semester where I'll have a workshop course in developing for Android.
So, is there a site as SourceForge for Android?

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to learn android???

Comment: you can check this http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=android&btn=Search+projects

Answer (score 1):

To learn android check following sites:

1. [how can i learn android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949818/how-can-i-learn-android)
2. [how can i learn android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475152/how-can-i-learn-android)
3. [Android developer's guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html)

For sample code visit following sites:

1. [Android samples](http://www.tutorials-android.com/code_examples/)
2. [Code Sample in Android](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/index.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps, Thank you. but i was more referring to a site where I can join an ongoing project, write a little feature or debug something, before making my own project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following website where a lot of open source projects can be downloaded

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/